# JavaFX: adapter, ObjectProperty and bidirectional binding

Tags: java, javafx

I want to understand how ObjectProperty works but still no luck.
I have the following POJO:

```
public class Article{

    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

    public Article(String title) {
        this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        LocalDateTime pv = this.dateTime;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("dateTime", pv, this.dateTime);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Now, I create objectProperty for dateTime field:

```
ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> dateTimeProperty=new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder().bean(article).name("dateTime").build();
```

And now I want to bind this dateTimeProperty to textField.textProperty(). And I have no idea how to do it: how will the data be formatted for showing dateTime in textField? How the instance of LocalDateTime will be created when I enter new date time in textField? We do have bidirectional binding. Please, explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create your bean as a JavaFX Bean

```
public class Article {
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> dateTime = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    public final ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> dateTimeProperty() {
         return dateTime;
    }
    public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime ldt) {
         dateTime.set(ldt);
    }
    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
         return dateTime.get();
    }
}
```

Then in your control you bind to the text control with a formatter

```
myTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(article.dateTimeProperty(), new LocalDateTimeStringConverter());
```

Comment: Won't this die when you try to edit the text field? It will try to parse the date/time on every text change, so you will have a ton of invalid values while editing. You need to only parse the value on commit.

Comment: Hmmm.. Not sure - I use a specialized converter which handles several different formats, therefore this wasn't an issue for me.  However, I believe that this is the standard way to process these items.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) on the text field:

```
// choose whatever formats you need here...
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/y H:m:s");

TextFormatter<LocalDateTime> textFormatter = new TextFormatter(new LocalDateTimeStringConverter(formatter, parser));
myTextField.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);
```

and then

```
textFormatter.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(dateTimeProperty);
```

If you want, you can also specify a filter on the `TextFormatter`, to limit editing to characters that only make sense in this context (though the details of that can get a bit tricky). Refer to the documentation for [`TextFormatter.Change`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html) for details.

Comment: Could you say how to bind objectProperty (from my example) to tableColumn? Or should I ask a new question?

Comment: For a table column, just set the cell value property to map to the property directly. I.e. you have `TableColumn<Article, LocalDateTime> column` and `column.setCellValueProperty(cellData -> new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder().bean(cellData.getValue()).name("dateTime")).build());`. (Of course that is much easier if you use JavaFX properties directly in your bean, instead of adapters.) If you need the table cell to be editable, just use a `TextFieldTableCell` with a converter (the converter the same as either answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I have no method `setCellValueProperty` in TableColumn.

Comment: Sorry, `setCellValueFactory`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. The only thing that I don't see is how to add XStringConverter as it was for TextField :`myTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(article.dateTimeProperty(), new LocalDateTimeStringConverter());`. How to add XStringConverter to TableColumn?

Comment: You don't add it to the table column: use a cell factory. Is the column editable?

Comment: Yes, the column is editable. And besides I want to control output in cell value for ObjectProperty. If I could to add XStringConverter I would be the happiest man in the world.

Comment: OK, for an editable cell jsut use a text field table cell with the converter set on the cell

Comment: i.e. `tableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new LocalDateTimeStringConverter(...)));`

Comment: Seems to work. Thank you very much for your time and help!